# Why it print out an empty array instead of the array appended with values for the first time in viewDidLoad()?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, viewdidload

I'd like to have an array appended with values from database in viewDidLoad() so that I can extract a value and assign it to an UILabel.text after loading the view.

The codes:

```
var tagArr = [Tag]()

  

          override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let AA = fetchTagPool()
        print(AA)
        
                
            }

 

   func fetchTagPool() -> [Tag]{
      
        API.Tag.observeTagPool {(tag) in
            self.tagArr.append(tag)
            print(self.tagArr)
        }

        return self.tagArr
    }
```

The result of `print(AA)` is an empty array as `[]` while that of `print(self.tagArr)` is the expected array appended with value from database.

How do I fix the code to make `print(AA)` work as `print(self.tagArr)` does?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `API.Tag.observeTagPool` is asynchronous and it will finish after `fetchTagPool()` has returned the empty `self.tagArr`.

You need to change `fetchTagPool` to return the value through a `callback` function like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // Note: This will print AA after viewDidLoad finishes
    // Use trailing closure syntax to pass the trailing closure
    // as "callback".  Then fetchTagPool calls "callback", this
    // closure will receive the value as AA and print it and
    // update the UILabel
    fetchTagPool() { AA in
        print(AA)

        // Use value to update a label
        myLabel.text = AA[0].name
    }

    print("This will print first")
}

func fetchTagPool(callback: ([Tag]) -> Void) {
      
    API.Tag.observeTagPool { tag in
        self.tagArr.append(tag)
        print(self.tagArr)
        callback(self.tagArr)
    }

}
```

---

If your `API.Tag.observeTagPool` runs on a background queue and doesn't return to the main queue to return its value, you should move to the main queue before updating the value in your property like this:

```
func fetchTagPool(callback: ([Tag]) -> Void) {
      
    API.Tag.observeTagPool { tag in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tagArr.append(tag)
            print(self.tagArr)
            callback(self.tagArr)
        }
    }

}
```