# How to extract values from the array after all values are injected into the array?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

[The solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63970418/why-it-print-out-an-empty-array-instead-of-the-array-appended-with-values-for-th) help me avoid the empty array but can't let me extract values beside array[0].
I'd like to extract 2 values after appending all values to the array.
array[0] is printed out successfully but the error message appeared as  "Index out of range" while I tried to print out array[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63970418/why-it-print-out-an-empty-array-instead-of-the-array-appended-with-values-for-th).

below is the code:

```
    var followingList = [User]()

    func fetchfollowingList(callback: @escaping ([User]) -> Void) {

        API.User.fetchFollowingList { followingUser in

            self.followingList.append(followingUser)
            callback(self.followingList)
          print(self.followingList)
        }
          print(self.followingList[0].displayName)
          print(self.followingList[1].displayName)
    }
```

the "print(self.followingList)" result in console:

```
[APP01.User]  
[APP01.User, APP01.User]   
[APP01.User, APP01.User, APP01.User]
```

I inferred that the **array[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63970418/why-it-print-out-an-empty-array-instead-of-the-array-appended-with-values-for-th)** is being extracted from the 1st array appended with only one value instead of the **3rd array** appended with all values and not knowing how to fix it.

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why it print out an empty array instead of the array appended with values for the first time in viewDidLoad()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63970418/why-it-print-out-an-empty-array-instead-of-the-array-appended-with-values-for-th). You have already asked this and gotten an answer to this question.

Comment: [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63970418/why-it-print-out-an-empty-array-instead-of-the-array-appended-with-values-for-th) help me avoid the empty array but can't let me extract the values besides the array[0].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function that fills the array is an `async` one, so when the compiler reaches the `print` state, it may not be filled **yet**. So you should check for that asynchronously too. Something like:

```
func fetchfollowingList(callback: @escaping ([User]) -> Void) {

    API.User.fetchFollowingList { followingUser in

        self.followingList.append(followingUser)
        callback(self.followingList)
        print(self.followingList)

        self.printIfNeeded() // <- Check everytime something appended
    }
}

func printIfNeeded() {
    guard followingList.count > 1 else { return } // Check the condition you need.

    print(self.followingList[0].displayName)
    print(self.followingList[1].displayName)
}
```

Comment: Really appreciated your answer and it does work. However, please let me explain further why it matters for me to access the array with all values appended: I need to call shuffled() method and extract 2 values from the array. Print(array[1]) is one of the ways to verify if there's multiple values in the array. " Futures & Promises" might be of help while I keep surveying this issue but still hard for me to understand. Any of your sample code to solve it is welcome.

Comment: There are multiple solutions for that. But you may want to think a bit about it and then if you didn't find any solutions, ask another question with the **tried code** embedded. Then I can help you with that my friend.